# Unable to run node.js application in FIPS mode on Bluemix

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, fips

Unable to run the node.js application created in Bluemix environment even after setting the variable FIPS_MODE to true on CF CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the node.js version 6 is used we would need to explicitly include the variable -enable-fips in the start command

eg: 
`{
   "start": "node --enable-fips app.js"
}`